# How to get Max from List<CustomType> and return whole type not only number?

Tags: c#

I have that list:

```
Custom custom1 = new Custom(1, OtherCustom);
Custom custom2 = new Custom(2, OtherCustom);
Custom custom3 = new Custom(3, OtherCustom);
List<Custom> list = new List<Custom>();
list.Add(custom1);
list.Add(custom2);
list.Add(custom3);
```

---

I am really noob. Can someone help me achieve such a thing? :V

```
Custom custom = MAX ( list )
custom ---> {3, OtherCustom}
```

I need to take max by first parameter and still return whole object.

Comment: Please post the code that defines the `Custom` class. I'm assuming those constructor arguments end up as public properties?

Comment: added an answer and explanation

Comment: custom does not exist. It was only example of my situation.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. There are so many dupes! Did you search? Some are even from Jon Skeet!

Comment: `MaxBy` - https://markheath.net/post/exploring-morelinq-3-maxby

Comment: This works: `list.Aggregate(list.First(), (a, x) => x.Num > a.Num ? x : a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is using `list.Max()` only and implement `IComparable<Custom>`, so your class would be:

```
public class Custom : IComparable<Custom>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public OtherCustom OtherCustom { get; set; }
    public Custom(int id, OtherCustom otherCustom)
    {
        Id = id;
        OtherCustom = otherCustom;
    }

    public int CompareTo([AllowNull] Custom other)
    {
        return Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
    }
}
```

And your max would pretty simple

```
Custom custom1 = new Custom(1, new OtherCustom());
Custom custom2 = new Custom(2, new OtherCustom());
Custom custom3 = new Custom(3, new OtherCustom());
Custom custom4 = new Custom(1, new OtherCustom());
List<Custom> list = new List<Custom>();
list.Add(custom1);
list.Add(custom2);
list.Add(custom3);
list.Add(custom4);

var item = list.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

this will return the max first parameter and it is a property of the `Custom Class`

```
var maxFirstParameterOfList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstParameterPropertyName).First();
```

if you want checking

```
var maxFirstParameterOfList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstParameterPropertyName).FirstOrDefault();

if (maxFirstParameterOfList != null)
{
    return maxFirstParameterOfList;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `OrderByDescending`... or use `Last()` instead of `First()`

Comment: i have edited it @JohnWu, thanks also for reminding

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what `OtherCustom` is, so I define a string to replace it.

You can get the "Max item" via linq as followed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Custom custom1 = new Custom(1, "OtherCustom1");
        Custom custom2 = new Custom(2, "OtherCustom2");
        Custom custom3 = new Custom(3, "OtherCustom3");
        List<Custom> list = new List<Custom>();
        list.Add(custom1);
        list.Add(custom2);
        list.Add(custom3);

        int max = list.Max(i => i.Num);
        Custom item = list.First(x => x.Num == max);
    }
}

class Custom
{
    int num;
    string otherCustom;

    public int Num
    {
        get { return num; }
    }
    public Custom(int n, string other)
    {
        num = n;
        otherCustom = other;
    }
}
```

Comment: that was exactly what i needed! That 2x lines. Thanks!

Comment: I would use `MaxBy` rather than this. This code passes through the list _twice_ (one to get the `Max`, then to find the entry with the `Max`.